# trying to set up a virtual environment, zsh: command not found: -m

Tags: macos, installation, pip, python-3.9

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment. I have a Mac, using Mac OS Big Sur 11.1. I have installed the latest stable version of python, but when I enter this command into the terminal window

```
-m pip install pipenv pip --upgrade
```

I get the following error

```
zsh: command not found: -m
```

before, it would say

"No module named pip"

Do I have to install pip separately with

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

I thought pip was included by default when you install python? I think I might have pip because when I type

```
python3 -m pip
```

into the command line, I get a long list of commands (install packages, download packages, etc.) General options... Thus should I install pip? one person on reddit said,

> Pip is not necessarily included with any version of Python. In many
> distributions, it must be installed separately.
>
> If python3 -m pip works, then you have a bad install, not a missing
> one.

thus did I incorrectly install python? When I was installing it there was no option to

> "add python to PATH"

Do I have to do this on a mac? If I input

```
python3 -V
```

in terminal, I get

```
Python 3.9.2
```

Thanks

Comment: i solved this by running, pip3 install pip --upgrade

Answer (score 1):

i solved this by running,

```
pip3 install pip --upgrade
```